# Automorphisms of pro-objects

Tags: category-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-group

Let $C$ be a small category and let $Pro(C)$ denote its pro-completion. Is it then true that $Aut(X) \cong \varprojlim_{i \in I} Aut(X_i)$ for all objects $X := \{X_i\}_{i \in I} \in Pro(C)$ ? What about when $C$ is a Galois category ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the case. Take $X=\mathbb{Z} \cup \{\frac{+}{-}\infty\}$ a two point compactification of $\mathbb{Z}$.

You can write it as the limit $\varprojlim \limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{-n ,\cdots ,n\}$, where the transition map from $\{-m, \cdots ,m\} $ to $\{-n,\cdots , n\}$ sends $k$ to $-n$ if $k<-n$, to $n$ if $k>n$ and to itself otherwise.

Take $f \in Aut(X)$ the translation by $1$. Then you cannot decompose it as a limit of automorphisms on $[-n,n]$, since $n-1$ would have to be sent to $n$ and the same goes for $n$, so resulting projection of $f$ would not be injective.

If we however assume that $Aut(X)$ is a profinite group for its open compact topology on $X$, then you can find some family $X_i$ such that $X \cong\varprojlim \limits_{i \in I} X_i$ and such that $Aut(X)\cong \varprojlim \limits_{i \in I} Aut(X_i)$, but it is not true for every choice of finite sets.

Comment: Thank you for the counter-example. Would you mind elaborating on your second point ? In particular, how might we assume that $Aut(X)$ is profinite ?

Comment: It's a it beyond the scope of Stack exchange, but as a profinite space, X is compact, so the continuous automorphisms of X are a topological group for the open compact topology. If that group happens to be profinite, you end up with an action of a profinite set on a profinite space, in which case you can write the profinite space as a projective limit of finite sets upon which the group acts. I'd recommend you to check the book of Ribes and Zaleskii on the profinite groups for the details concerning the actions of profinite groups on profinite spaces.

Comment: This is actually the toy example that I was working with. I decided to post the question when I was having trouble adapting this result to pro-representable functors $F: C \to FinSets$.

Comment: @DatMinhHa It's an interesting coincidence that we are working on something very similar around the same time. I am doing a thesis on profinite graphs, but I am also currently interested in generalizing certain classical results on profinite sets/ groups to a category-theory setting. I will post here relevant reference if I find something. In the mean time, good luck.